# How to tell bash not to expand $_ variable?

Tags: perl, bash

I want to use some perl line, like this:

```
perl -pe "$_=~s///e"
```

The problem is, bash keeps expanding the "$_" variable. I could put the perl expression into single quotes, but that would prevent me from adding some variables into a script.

Is there a way stop bash from expanding "$_" variable?

Comment: Attention closer: don’t be ridiculous.  Shell programming questions absolutely belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: You don't *need*  to use the `$_` variable there.

Comment: @TLP - that was just an example. In the real script, I really *needed* it. :)

Comment: @Rogach Pardon me for being blunt, but people often think they need things they don't. If you want specifics, you need to be specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
perl -pe '$_=~s///e'
```

or

```
perl -pe "\$_=~s///e"
```

Answer (score 5):

First off: You know that you can use `$ENV{myvariable}` to access environment variables, right? And that you do not need to specify `$_` when using `m//`, `s///` and `tr///`?

Furthermore, if you want to pass variables to perl, there are other ways of doing that besides trying to interpolate shell variables into your perl code.

```
perl -we 'my ($var1, $var2, $var3) = @ARGV;' "$MYFOO" "$BAR" "$baz"
```

If your shell variables do not contain whitespace, you can dispense with the quoting.

Now, if you want to use the `-p` or `-n` switches, there are ways around that too.

```
perl -pwe 'BEGIN { my $var1 = shift; my $var2 = shift } #code goes here'
    "$MYFOO" "$BAR" file1 file2
```

Using `shift` in a BEGIN statement will remove variables from `@ARGV` so that they are not used by the implicit `while` loop of the `-p` and `-n` switches.

Comment: `ENV` in perl is specifically for environment variables, not shell variables generally.

Answer (score 1):

Mix-and-match.

```
perl -pe '$_=~s///e; echo "'"$idontknowperl"'"'
```

As long as the quoted sections butt up against each other it will be considered a single argument.

Comment: Well yes, but the Perl compiler isn’t going to be pleased that you called an `echo` method/function. :)